# How to automatically slide the pages in page slider HarmonyOS?

Tags: java, android, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers, harmonyos

I have implemented a custom page slider indicator inspired by [ArcPageIndicator](https://github.com/BeppiMenozzi/ArcPageIndicator/blob/master/sample/src/main/java/it/beppi/arcpageindicator_sample/SampleActivity.java) in HarmonyOS and to test that I wanted to slide the pages using the page slider automatically. How Can I do that in HarmonyOS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a ScrollView component in the XML file under the layout directory. ScrollView requires the support of a layout. The following uses DirectionalLayout as an example.

```
<ScrollView
    ohos:id="$+id:scrollview"
    ohos:height="300vp"
    ohos:width="300vp"
    ohos:background_element="#FFDEAD"
    ohos:top_margin="32vp"
    ohos:bottom_padding="16vp"
    ohos:layout_alignment="horizontal_center">
    <DirectionalLayout
        ohos:height="match_content"
        ohos:width="match_content">
        <!-- $media:plant: image resource referenced in the media directory-->
        <Image
            ohos:width="300vp"
            ohos:height="match_content"
            ohos:top_margin="16vp"
            ohos:image_src="$media:plant"/>
        <!-- Add content to be displayed -->
        ...
    </DirectionalLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

For more details, see [scrollView of the Java UI](https://developer.harmonyos.com/en/docs/documentation/doc-guides/ui-java-component-scrollview-0000001060965602).